# UK Visitor Visa - Visiting for 4 days

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am planning to apply for my UK visitor visa for 4 days. I will be having a stop over and visit London on my way to my husband's graduation in US. After his graduation, we will stay there for approx. 4 months and then will return back to our home country.

I am the primary applicant and I have enough  in my savings account for UK and US trips. Am I eligible to apply for a UK visitor visa?

Please advise.

Comment: Anybody can apply for a UK visitor visa. What exactly do you actually want to know?

Comment: @MichaelHampton What I want to know is, my husband can travel to UK with his visitor visa. Should I mention that my husband is visiting with me and he already has a visa. Or it doesn't matter as I am the primary applicant.

Comment: The visa application asks who will travel with you. You should fill this correctly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Okay, even though he won't be applying for a visa, correct? Because, for this trip, I will be paying from my savings account and we'll be staying in a hotel for 3 nights.

Comment: You should just answer the questions on the form correctly. They are plain English and do not have unexpected meanings. When it asks if your spouse is travelling with you, you answer yes because that is what is actually the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be eligible for a UK Standard Visitor visa you must show that:

- you’ll leave the UK at the end of your visit
- you’re able to support yourself and any dependents for the duration of your trip
- you’re able to pay for your return or onward journey and any other costs relating to your visit
- you have proof of any business or other activities you want to do in the UK, as allowed by the Visitor Rules

Source: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/eligibility

You must answer the question about any travelling companions correctly, regardless of whether they need to apply for a visa or not. Include evidence of your eligibility to enter the US (ESTA or visa) with your application, to show UKVI that you can complete your stated travel itinerary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't have my US visa yet. I will apply for one after my UK visa as I have to send documents to an embassy in a different country and processing times may vary. US consulate is in our country and we can get appointments for visa interview within 2 weeks time. Therefore, I thought of applying to UK first and then apply for US. Will that be okay to travel like that?

Comment: @user9431057 The typical advice is to apply for visas in reverse order, starting with the final destination and working backwards to the first. Doing it that way will be strong proof of your intention to leave the UK and your eligibility to enter the US. Doing it the other way round (applying to the UK first) might increase your chance of refusal, depending on your overall risk profile eg citizenship, country of residence if applicable, ties to home.